# Static data members

Tags: c++, json, static

In order to support a json interface, currently the json request, response are stored in a map and each class contains static member variables which are the "keys" for accessing the map when recieving from json side or when sending to json side. Typical class would look like

```
struct JsonCenterOfGravity
{
static const QString COMMAND_NAME = "GetCoG";
static const QString COG = "COG";
static const QString MASS = "MASS"
QVariantMap map;
};
```

And clients can access the values using, if response is JsonCenterOfGravity response,

```
response.map.value(JsonCenterOfGravity::COG);
```

There will be quite a few request/response classes like this. The main reason for the implementation like this is to not code extensively to have a better interface since the project is quite time critical. This will generate lot of static data in the program and also the implementation itself is quite 'C' like so to say.

My question is how bad is this and what are the problems of using zillions of static data.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I really do not see a way of doing it that will produce a program with a smaller memory footprint.  Since it is static only one instance will be declared, and you need that data somewhere in your program in order to serialize and deserialize the JSON.

Comment: yes, only thing I can think is making them non static will make a lesser memory footprint practically as the objects will be only created for serialize and deserialize in run time.